# How can I set a tkinter window to open only for the first time user runs the program and never open again?

Tags: python, windows, user-interface, tkinter

I have been designing a Voice Assistant app using Python and tkinter. I want the user to set the default directories in which to search for songs, movies etc. This has to happen only for the first time the user runs the program and never again until he wishes to change the directories later which he would be able to do with a settings button. Is there any way to create a tkinter window that would display only for the first time the user runs the program by default and never display again until the user wishes to do so?

Comment: Your program can check whether a configuration file exists, if yes, read the parameters from the file, otherwise, open the window to let user to set the parameters and save them to the configuration file.  But how can the user clicks a settings button if there is no window shown?

Comment: you can create a txt file and read it each time a person opens the app, and inside of it there should b a text like firsttime = 0 (false) or 1 (true) its totally yourwish, and then read the data and ise `if firsttime=0:` make window u need, `else` continue with ur normal code, almost same idea as @acw1668 configuration file method

Answer (score 0):

You need to store some sort of artifact on the filesystem to answer the question "has this program run before?". For example, it could create a file named **~/.myprogramrc**. Next, just check for the existence of that file, and open up the GUI if the file doesn't exist.

```
class App(tk.Tk):

    def __init__(self):
        rc_file = Path.home() / ".myapprc"
        if not rc_file.exists():
            # a side effect of this should create the file .myapprc
            # in the home directory.
            config = self.prompt_for_config(rc_file)
        else:
            config = self.read_config(rc_file)
```